# What page dimensions should I use when designing a book for Kindle with the print replica option?

Tags: page-layout, ebook, kindle

I'm wanting to create a PDF via LaTeX that I can ideally use with Kindle Create's Print Replica option.

What are good settings for the PDF? What should the height and width of the page be? What are the ideal page margins?

Answer (score 0):

Width must be within 4"-8.5" (10.16-21.59 cm). 
Height must be within 6"-11.69" (15.24-29.69 cm).

Seems 6x9" is a common trim size.

Additional information can be found in the [Amazon Kindle Print Options](https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G201834180#:%7E:text=Width%20must%20be%20within%204,(15.24%2D29.69%20cm).) help section.

Comment: The link talks about paperbacks. That's about letting Amazon print your book. Print Replica is an option for ebooks that can be read on the Kindle.

Comment: Print Replica is merely a more restrictive PDF format compared to the standard HTML/XML ebook format - i.e. - no text/image resizing, etc.. The overall dimensions should generally be in line with printing - whether through Amazon printing or end user home printing. What *specific* dimensions to make any book is up to the designer. There are common sizes 6x9", 8.5x11", etc. But 7x10" works just as well.

Comment: If I have a print book the specific dimensions are up to the designer. If I however design for the Kindle, then my design is constrained by the size of the screen of the kindle.

Comment: I haven't directly used it, but what I've read the PDF for the Print Replica e-book is merely a *basis* which Kindle then builds a standard e-book (e-pub) from for you. So, you get the PDF print version, and an auto-generated epub version. The PDF should adhere to print sizes. Other than the cover for the epub version, the sizes are dynamic and scale to the device.

Comment: This all may be getting too broad and unfocused. There are a mountain of links out there to aid in creating Print Replica ebooks for Kindle. I'll stress it's not my area of expertise. But if I were to create a print replica ebook, I'd create the PDF at the size I want, then delve into what Kindle Create allows in terms of alterations from the base PDF. One could merely create a 4 page PDF and do some internal testing.